# Adding dummy customers for development in Opencart 2.X

Tags: jquery, opencart, opencart2.x

**Not a question, but a note for posterity**

As developers, we have a need to over-and-over install different versions of Opencart, populate products, customers etc., depending on the nature of the specific dev task. Often we use DB tools like PhpMyAdmin to create some dummy entries or import from another database.

Today, I just needed to create 20 - 30 customers in 2 groups, some are newsletter subscribers and some are not.
I am sort of sick and tired of doing this in DB, so I came up with another method bellow.

Answer (score 0):

I used JavaScript to populate form fields on "Add Customer" page in Admin.

In JavaScript console, paste the following (edited to your needs):

```
$('#input-customer-group').val(2)
$('#input-firstname').val('D-' + Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '').substr(0, 4))
$('#input-lastname').val(Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '').substr(0, 5))
$('#input-email').val('D_' + Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '').substr(0, 4) +'@'+ Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '').substr(0, 5) +'.com')
$('#input-telephone').val(Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '').substr(0, 7))
$('#input-password').val('test')
$('#input-confirm').val('test')
$('#input-newsletter').val(0)
$('button[type="submit"]').click()
```

Hit `Enter`

On Customer List page that you are redirected to, In JavaScript console, paste the following:

```
 window.location.href = $('div.pull-right').find('a').attr('href')
```

Hit `Enter`

Now you are back to Add Customer page.

Now you just cycle through previous commands to add as many users as you need, editing your code as needed

`UP ARROW` + `UP ARROW` + `ENTER`

[image]